# what happen if the valid set AUC higher than training AUC?

Tags: machine-learning, cart, auc, boosting

Here is the scenario . I have about 40 million instances for training, 18 million instances for testing. I use 37 million instances for training and 3 million for validation during the training. I found something strange.

The training AUC is about 0.977, the validation AUC is about 0.984, however, the test AUC is 0.968. The model is lightgbm. So, why the training AUC is lower than validation AUC. And the test AUC is much lower than validation. Is it overfitting?

Answer (score 2):

These might all be the same AUC. AUC is just a calculation with some kind of confidence interval around it. Most software doesn't calculate this interval for you, but you could do it yourself; use cross-validation to re-run the same model with the same data but varying the seed.

Short answer: you may have a model that generalizes very well with an AUC of .977 +/- .01.